How to fill Sharepoint list form on adding by Event Receiver
I have got custom list. I must Auto fill this list by Event Receiver. When the form is opening. The same elements should be auto filled.
What code should I write ? I have only now:
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            //properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = "123456789";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// An item was updated.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
              base.ItemUpdated(properties);
        }


The requirement is not clear as event receivers are fired after the item's data is saved to SharePoint. All fields/columns values should be available in the SPItemEventProperties parameters after the SP Form is submitted, and you would able to process them further. What does it mean to auto-fill here? The item that has just been saved should be retrieved and then used for creating a new item?

Every list has got their forms. I won't use Infopath, poweraps and power automate because I has got Server version. How could I put values info default list form.

For the out-of-the-box list forms, the only way to set default values for each column showing up on the NewForm is to add Default value: for the column. You can go to the list settings then column settings and there is an option to set the Default Value

Please refer to following code
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdating(properties);
    using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
    {

        SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;

        currentItem["DepartVersion"] = "The Item Was changed, it was: "  + currentItem["DepartVersion"].ToString();

        try
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            currentItem.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // catch exception
        }
        finally
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }            
    }
}

Here is the document for more details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/handle-list-item-events-in-the-provider-hosted-add-in
